# Complexity of solving a system of linear equations over a number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, computational-complexity

Given a system of linear equations in $k$ variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ with coefficients that are complex algebraic numbers of height at most H and degree at most $d$, what is the time complexity of solving this system as a function of $k, d, H$? Is this in polynomial time?

EDIT: Let me fix that the algebraic numbers that are coefficients of the linear equation be represented by the minimal polynomial and the specific root to sufficient accuracy (which is determined by the root separation bound). Does the complexity change if the algebraci numbers are represented as vectors over some extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it wasn't, though I don't know the complexity due to the encoding for the algebraic numbers. One can always diagonalize the matrix in $n^3$ ish time, all those manipulations give new algebraic numbers. If one could show the new degrees aren't too big and the simplifications from symbolic solving are quick, we're done.

Comment: Lets say we encode the algebraic numbers by giving the minimal polynomial and using the root separation bound to specify the algebraic numbers. Does the representation really change the complexity of the problem? If I use standard representation, my worry is that if each coefficient is a $\sqrt{p_i}$ for a distinct prime, the representation might turn out to be huge.

Comment: I've seen some representations use symbolic representations (so sqrts, e, etc) and it seemed the alphabet used could matter. Minimal polynomials is a good choice. Then the question methinks is what is the maximal degree we need to express a linear combination of n degree d algebraic numbers. If that's poly, we're fine...

Comment: It is certainly possible to solve in polynomial time.  The choice of representation should take into account cost of all arithmetic (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division).

Comment: can you elaborate/point to a reference? i'm sure it is possible, but i want to know the dependence of running time on height and degree.

Comment: Sure, I'll summarize some references for you.  I would have seen your Comment earlier if you'd used the `@username` syntax to ping me.